# Editing a Python function in real-time

Tags: python-2.7

I'm a new Python user. I've been trying to get a setup script to work -- unsuccessfully. What I have found is that, while simply importing the script returns a fatal error, I can rewrite it line by line in real-time. Every time I make an error or typo, Python kicks me out of the continuing '...' edit mode and into '>>>' mode which, with my limited knowledge means that I have to start all over. The problem is that one function passes more than 100 lines of code. If I get an error in the middle, at this stage of my knowledge, I have to begin it again.

Is there some way to pick the function writing back up where I left off, before the typo?

Answer (score 1):

If you use python IDLE (or any other IDE...there are tons of them listed [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments)), you will have what's called a REPL (read-evaluate-print-loop) that will make your life much easier!  You can select just a small part of your code, run it, see its effects, make edits, re-run it, run the next part, etc.

Comment: everyone's ignorance was embarrassing when they were getting started.

http://www.xkcd.com/1053/